# GetStrProp does not find property on object

Tags: delphi, rtti

I'm trying to get the properties of a TObject with their name like so:

```
    var key           := GetStrProp(table.Item, keyName);
    var value         := GetStrProp(table.Item, valueName);
```

The code above returns an error saying it cannot find property 'CODE' on the object (the keyName contains 'CODE'). The same happens for the valueName.

I tested the content of the object with the code below, it does contain the property CODE and the value also contains what I expect.

```
    var item          := table.Item as TdciPROJECTRESULTAATTYPE;
    var code          := item.CODE;
    var value         := item.DESCRIPTION;
```

What is wrong with the first 2 lines?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code, but there might be something "wrong" with the TdciPROJECTRESULTAATTYPE class.

`GetStrProp` is one of Delphi's "old-style" RTTI methods from the `TypInfo` unit. The old RTTI was only generating type information for published properties of objects compiled with the {M+} compiler directive (and their descendants). TdciPROJECTRESULTAATTYPE most likely does not have those old-style RTTI.

If you have a modern version of Delphi, it offers more "modern" RTTI functions(in unit `RTTI`), that can access way more informations about objects (Though, I don't remember at this time the exact inclusion rules). Those *may* allow you to access your property through RTTI.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ken for pointing me in the right direction. I've created a little function that does what I need just fine. Here's the code.

```
class function TComboboxHelper<TTable>.GetPropertyValue(obj: TObject; name: string) : TValue;
begin
  Result              := nil;

  var rttiContext     := TRttiContext.Create;

  try
    var classType     := obj.ClassType;
    var itemType      := rttiContext.GetType(classType);
    var propType      := itemType.GetProperty(name);

    Result            := propType.GetValue(obj);

  finally
    rttiContext.Free;

  end;

end;
```

You can use it like so:

```
    var key           := GetPropertyValue(table.Item, keyName).AsString;
    var value         := GetPropertyValue(table.Item, valueName).AsString;
```